# django.db.utils.DataError: integer out of range

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Postgres Database in my django project. I have a model called enquiry

```
class Enquiry(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user_address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    user_mobile = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And I createed a ffunction to create a new enquiry

```
Enquiry.objects.create(
            product_name = product_name,
            product_id = product_id,
            user_name = user_name,
            user_email = user_email,
            user_address="None",
            user_mobile = user_mobile
    )
```

But I get an error

`django.db.utils.DataError: integer out of range`

how to solve this?

Comment: Please mark this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73876885/django-db-utils-dataerror-integer-out-of-range/73876917#73876917) as correct if it solved your problem

Answer (score 3):

Try using [BigIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield) if your integers are that big. From the documentation:

> A 64-bit integer, much like an IntegerField except that it is guaranteed to fit numbers from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. The admin represents this as an  (a single-line input).